# Gitlab: redirection to non resolvable hostname

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I've installed Gitlab on Ubuntu 14.04 with the 2 minutes installation doc and when I access the ui http://server_ip, I'm redirected towards http://hostname/users/sign_in
As hostname is not resolvable I cannot accesd this url. I'm sure I missed something but cannot figure out what.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the 'external_url' field in your `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file then run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

See http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html for more details.